# How to re-write/rename HTML output of a View Block wrapper ID?

Tags: 7, views

Drupal newbie here. Would like to know how do I change the HTML wrapper ID of a View Block?

Currently I have a view that has two blocks.

1. The first block is the "Do's" block.
   HTML output: 
   `<section id="block-views-do-s-block" class="block block-views contextual-links-region block-do-s-block block-views-do-s-block odd">`
2. The second one is a "Don'ts" block. 
   HTML output: `<section id="block-views-do-s-block-1" class="block block-views contextual-links-region block-do-s-block-1 block-views-do-s-block-1 even">`

I would like to rename the "id" of the second block to make it more intuitive.

Screenshot: https://img.skitch.com/20120430-p8dtxdx7h8qa5augidx9gudjbn.jpg

How to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to you view select block display "Do's" then Advanced -> OTHER -> Machine Name change this and it''ll change the id of your block.

Comment: Thank you! Totally missed out the "Advanced" section >.<